# The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:12349/authorize/ did not match a registered redirect URI

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm getting this error while trying to run my c# console application... I am trying to call google calender api v3 to fetch calender and add event to calender. According to the sample code from google-api-dotnet-client I am doing this.( https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp/Program.vb?repo=samples ) Here is the vb.net code. I am using this sample after converting it to c# code.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new Program().Run().Wait();
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            foreach (var e in ex.InnerExceptions)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        UserCredential credential;
        IList<string> scopes = new List<string>();

        CalendarService service;
        scopes.Add(CalendarService.Scope.Calendar);


        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            // problem occuring during executing this statement.
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                scopes,
                "user", CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("Calender.SampleApp") );
        }

        BaseClientService.Initializer initializer = new BaseClientService.Initializer();
        initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
        initializer.ApplicationName = "C# Calendar Sample";

        service = new CalendarService(initializer);

        Event newEvent = new Event();

        newEvent.Summary = "Appointment";
        newEvent.Description = "Need to meet my Uncle";

        IList<EventReminder> reminders = new List<EventReminder>();
        reminders.Add(new EventReminder { Method = "sms", Minutes = 10 });
        newEvent.Reminders = new Event.RemindersData { UseDefault = false, Overrides = reminders };

        newEvent.Recurrence = new String[] { "DTSTART;TZID=Bangladesh Standard Time:20140124T163000;RRULE:FREQ=DAILY" };

        IList<EventAttendee> attendees = new List<EventAttendee>();
        attendees.Add(new EventAttendee { Email = "hannan.cse.m@gmail.com", Organizer = true, DisplayName = "Hannan" });
        newEvent.Attendees = attendees;

        newEvent.GuestsCanInviteOthers = false;
        newEvent.GuestsCanModify = false;
        newEvent.GuestsCanSeeOtherGuests = false;
        newEvent.Location = "Dhaka, Bangladesh";
        newEvent.Start = new EventDateTime { DateTime = DateTime.Now, TimeZone = "Bangladesh Standard Time" };

        Event recurringEvent = service.Events.Insert(newEvent, "primary").Execute();

        var list = await service.CalendarList.List().ExecuteAsync();
    }
}
```

This is my redirect URIs in my GoogleDevelopers Console project.

```
Redirect URIs: http://localhost:7744/authorize/
```

And this is the error message shown in browser.

[image]

I couldn't find any way to resolve this problem. Some help will be appreciable. I also search all the realted post in stackoverflow. But I couldn't find it's solution.

Comment: Port numbers don't match, and port numbers are an important part of the identity of an HTTP uri.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I know. But i didn't define any redirect uri in my console application.  How to define that.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever how can I defineredirect uri from console application during matching credintial???

Comment: You don't need to define redirect uri in console application while authenticating. Please see my answer I think this will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you are doing something wrong while "create client id" in GoogleDevelopers Console. Make sure that you have chosed "Installed application" in application type to access your project from console application.

Have a look in the attached image. According to request type you must create clientid
and credintials in your registered application in Google Developers Console.

You don't need to define redirect uri in console application while authenticating.

[image]

Comment: If you are using console application then select Other for "create client id"

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error on a simple test program (https://ctrlq.org/google.apps.script/docs/guides/rest/quickstart/dotnet.html), and it happens to be the client_secret.json was th wrong one, download it again and it worked.